# Insertion Sort Function Error

Tags: javascript, arrays, insertion-sort

In order to do this, the insert function will need to make room for value by moving items that are greater than value to the right. It should start at rightIndex, and stop when it finds an item that is less than or equal to value, or when it reaches the beginning of the array. Once the function has made room for value, it can write value to the array.

```
var insert = function(array, rightIndex, value) {
    var key = value;
    for(var i = rightIndex; array[i] > value ; i = i - 1)
    {
        array[rightIndex + 1] = array[rightIndex];
    }
    array[i+1] = value;
};
```

Why My this function doesn`t work correctly after I input this array !

```
var array = [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 2, 9, 6];
```

It Shows this result:

```
insert(array, 4, 2);

2,5,7,11,13,13,9,6
```

Comment: what you want to acheive?

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 9, 6
I want this answer, The question is completely clear

Comment: That was also not clear to me. Please update with expected and actual and create a working snippet

Comment: Hm, do all of your assertions pass?
It is the error occurs, my code do the insertion sort algorithm but somethings wrong here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The line that shuffles items to the right needs editing

Change your line that currently reads:

```
array[rightIndex + 1] = array[rightIndex];
```

to read as follows:

```
array[i + 1] = array[i];
```

In your code as currently written, the `rightIndex`'th item is repeatedly being pasted into the  `rightIndex+1`'th position. This is why you are getting two `13`s in your result.

So your code is almost right already!

#### Explicitly check for the beginning of the array

You can change the for loop to ensure you never go left of the start of the array.

```
for(var i = rightIndex; i>=0 && array[i] > value ; i = i - 1)
```

Inserting the `i>=0 &&` means that when `i` falls below 0, Javascript knows to end the loop. Otherwise it will attempt to read the element `array[-1]`, which is undefined. Luckily the test will still work, because a comparison of any number (even negative) with "undefined", will be false. But it is much better style to explicitly test for this rather than rely on the quirk of the language. The reason is that if you were to apply the same algorithm in another language, the `array[-1]` might be an error.

Comment: array[rightIndex + 1] = array[rightIndex];
Its the same as above

Comment: Instead of relying on the array's undefined values at negative indices, can you explicitly check that you're at the beginning of the array?

Yeah it works, But this lines comes up, What it says

Comment: @MuhammadHamza - When you say `Its the same as above` yes, but `array[i + 1] = array[i];` is not - and that change produces your expected output

Comment: How can I explicitly check that I am at the beginning of the array? Instead of relying on the array's undefined values at negative indices ?




How ?

Comment: for(var i = rightIndex; i>0 && array[i] > value ; i = i - 1)

I enter this line , But the error remains the same

Comment: Where are you getting this error? Sounds like it is from a tutorial? It is not the type of error I would expect to see from a Javascript  interpreter.

Comment: And by the way, sorry, I should have said `i>=0` not `i>0`.

Answer (score 0):

inserting value into array works correctly with sorted array, in this case your array is not sorted.

```
var array = [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 2, 9, 6];
```

you need to first sort the array, for that use this

```
var array = [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 2, 9, 6];

array = arra.sort(function (a, b) {  return a - b;  });

array = array.sort((a, b) => a - b);

//outputs:  2, 3, 5, 6 , 7, 9, 11, 13
```

then you can insert into this array as sorted

For that you can try something like this

```
var array = [2, 3, 5, 6 , 7, 9, 11, 13];
var element = 2;

function insert(element, array) {
   array.push(element);

   array.sort(function(a, b) {
       return a - b;
   });

   return array;
}


//outputs:  2, 2, 3, 5, 6 , 7, 9, 11, 13
```